# НЕ работает js скрипт?

Tags: php, javascript

Имеют такой скрипт - php + js и он не работает - даже Алерт в начале не показывается? почему??

```
 <script>
alert('sdsd');
var valves = new Array();
<?php
$arrco = 0;
$prev = explode(",",$get['obem']);
foreach ($prev as $value) {
?>

valves[<?php echo $arrco; ?>] = '<?php echo $value; ?>';

<?php
$arrco++;
echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
 }
 ?>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы выводите теги `<option>` внутри тега `<script>`. Из-за этого в скрипте появляются синтаксические ошибки, из-за которых, в свою очередь, браузер не может этот скрипт выполнить. Внутри тега `<script>` должен бвть только JS-код, HTML-теги нужно выводить вне его. Вам понадобится второй цикл, который это сделает.

Вообще, возьмите за привычку при любом подозрительном выполнении (или невыполнении) JS открывать консоль разработчика и смотреть, что выводится во вкладке Console и в инспекторе элементов. Это позволит быстро отловить подобные ошибки. Чтобы вызвать консоль, нажмите в браузере F12 или Ctrl+Shift+I.

Comment: вы правы! надеюсь админы взывут к моим просьбам  и надеюсь ваш ответ засчитается вам в репутацию)